# Loop animations and/or fast animations in Javascript possible?

Tags: javascript, animation, background-image, settimeout, setinterval

I've this code:

```
var run_anim = "";
var anim_array = ["\animations\pic_1.gif",
                  "\animations\pic_2.gif",
                  "\animations\pic_3.gif",
                  "\animations\pic_4.gif"]

function changeBackgroundURL(elementId, backgroundURL){
    run_anim = "false";
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.background=backgroundURL;
}

function mouseover_anim(elementName){
    run_anim = "true";
    changeBackgroundURL(elementName,anim_array[0]);
    while(run_anim=="true"){
        setTimeout(function(){changeBackgroundURL(elementName,anim_array[1]) parameter = null},30);
        setTimeout(function(){changeBackgroundURL(elementName,anim_array[2]) parameter = null},40);
        setTimeout(function(){changeBackgroundURL(elementName,anim_array[3]) parameter = null},20); 
    }
}
```

I'm running this line:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,95,91"
            onMouseOver="mouseover_anim('div_1')" 
            onMouseOut="changeBackground('div_1', 'pic_static.gif')">
```

When I run it, the applications uses much CPU and I need to close the browser. It looks like the while-loop (which is always true) blocks the hole system (but I don't see any picture changing). I also can't see any error message while debugging in the browser. I also tried preloading the pics (code not posted above), but it still didn't  work.

The code **only** works if I *disable the while-loop* and *set a longer timeout* like this:

```
function mouseover_anim(elementName){
    changeBackgroundURL(elementName,anim_array[0]);
    setTimeout(function(){changeBackgroundURL(elementName,anim_array[1]) parameter = null},300);
    setTimeout(function(){changeBackgroundURL(elementName,anim_array[2]) parameter = null},400);
    setTimeout(function(){changeBackgroundURL(elementName,anim_array[3]) parameter = null},200); 
}
```

So is it impossible to create loop animations and/or fast animations with Javascript? Or do you have any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: PS: The "parameter = null" is needed due to garbage collection in IE: http://www.makemineatriple.com/2007/10/passing-parameters-to-a-function-called-with-settimeout

Comment: the 300 / 30 milli-secs is too frequent - try to change it to something that makes more sense like 3 secs. Also, you don't want to set 3 functions to be called every X minutes, what you do want is to use `setTimeout` with only one function that will rotate between the pics

Comment: More sense? An animation got 25 pic/sec at least, so that's 40ms. And I need those functions, because not every pic stays the same time, this is needed to get dynamics into the animation (I updated that...)

Comment: On the last comment I meant: `setInterval` not `setTimeout`...

Answer (score 1):

@alfasin if @Marcus wants it to be a fast animation, 3 second timeout is too much, so maybe something about 100 milli-secs? Second thing - use true, not "true" - can you see the difference? :) And the last, but most important thing - use setInterval to call your functions every n milliseconds, and you won't have the problem with browser crashing (of course you need to remember to clearInterval, otherwise it will run endlessly

Since I have a spare minute, here's the almost complete code:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    // do your stuff here

    // write condition, that when satisfied clears this interval
    //clearInterval(intervalId);
}, 100);
```

Comment: Allright, I'll try it with "setIntervall" and we'll see what it does. ;-)

Comment: Well @Marcus - it sets interval ;)

Comment: Yup, I tried your solution and there is "some" movement, but it really looks like 30ms aren't working, rather 100ms or 200ms. Too bad. (So Javascript is not usable for fast animations, that's what I already thought before)

Comment: I'd be glad if you could accept my answer. And about these 30ms - I vaguely remember that some browsers (if not all) limit setInterval frequency to about 20ms. If you think, your images are being swapped too slowly, maybe you should try to preload them? This delay you're experiencing maybe occur because 70ms is the time the browser needs to load an image? And another thing - maybe just these images of yours are too different from one another, and because of that the animation doesn't look smooth? And as my final word - use jQuery or other framework for such animations.

Comment: As I said in the question, I'm already preloading them. Your solution did only partly work, so I gave you some upvotes. ;D

Comment: @alfasin: this solution is only partly correct because the "write condition, that when satisfied clears this interval //clearInterval(intervalId);" doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it works for me (I changed the images names/path and tested locally on FF & chrome):

```
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">  
    div {  
        position: absolute;
        left:   200px;
        top:    200px;
        width:  800px;  
        height: 900px;  
        style: "background: url(\"1.jpg\")";
    }  
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var anim_array = ["url(\"1.jpg\")",
                  "url(\"2.jpg\")",
                  "url(\"3.jpg\")",
                  "url(\"4.jpg\")"]

function changeBackgroundURL(backgroundURL){
    document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundImage = backgroundURL;
}

function mouseover_anim(){
    var bg = document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundImage;
    if(bg === anim_array[0] || bg === ""){
        bg = anim_array[1];
    }
    else if(bg === anim_array[1]){
        bg = anim_array[2];
    }
    else if(bg === anim_array[2]){
        bg = anim_array[3];
    }
    else if(bg === anim_array[3]){
        bg = anim_array[0];
    }
    changeBackgroundURL(bg);    
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <img src ="1.jpg" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
    <map name="planetmap">
        <area shape="rect" id="1" coords="0,0,200,200" onMouseOver="setTimeout(mouseover_anim,3000);" >
    </map>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The same link for you to learn how to animate (Animation = Picture x Time): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sGM63yJUoc

Comment: Thanks but I'm not interested in learning how to animate using Maya...
I was trying to help - but since you already figured it out there's no point to continue here...

Comment: This is not only about how to animate using Maya, this is how to animate all kinds of animations with every available tool. If you want to learn how create realistic animation, you need to watch it. ;-)